# Couldn't import module in Angular2

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, angular, npm, asp.net-core

I've created project with [JavaScriptServices](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices) and I would like to use   [ng2-truncate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-truncate) but I'm getting an error:

> Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Unexpected
>   value 'TruncateModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'

Here's some part of my code:

*package.json*

```
"ng2-truncate": "^1.3.2" -> added in dependencies section
```

*app.module.ts*

```
import { TruncateModule } from 'ng2-truncate';
@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    //more components
    imports: [
        UniversalModule, // Must be first import. This automatically imports BrowserModule, HttpModule, and JsonpModule too.
        TruncateModule,
       //more modules
    ]
})
```

*webpack.config.vendor.js*

```
...
    entry: {
        vendor: [
            ...
            'ng2-truncate',
           ....
        ]
..
```

Do you know what it's wrong?